# Changing label color of a label in a different layer

Tags: ios, objective-c, colors, cocos2d-iphone

So I have a scene called `MainScene` where `CCScrollView` `UpgradesScroller` containing layer called `UpgradesNew` is located. I have a button that when tapped in `MainScene`, should set `hasItem` boolean to `YES` and then when the layer `UpgradesNew` is unhidden, a labels color should be changed based on the output of the boolean.

Here is what I tried.

Setting `hasItem` to true:

```
-(void) buyItem {
        hasItem = true;
    }
}
```

In `MainScene` this is the method used when `UpgradesNew` is unhidden.

```
-(void)Upgrades {
    UpgradesNew *upNew = [[UpgradesNew alloc]init];
    [upNew changeColor];
    if (upgradesScroller.visible == NO) {
        upgradesScroller.visible = YES;
    } else if (upgradesScroller.visible == YES) {
        upgradesScroller.visible = NO;
    }
}
```

In `UpgradesNew`

```
-(void)changeColor {
    if (hasItem == true) {
        label.color = [CCColor greenColor];
        NSLog(@"changecolor");
    }
}
```

I think the problem is because I'm allocating an empty instance of UpgradesNew. But I'm not sure how to do it the right way.

Comment: What's CCScrollView?  What's CCColor?  Why are you using `true` rather than `YES` in Objective-C code?  Why are you using `==` to check a `bool` in an `if`?

Comment: It's cocos2d.. true is the same thing as yes. == is used because YES/NO and true/false are ints (0 and 1 respectively)

Comment: Which evaluate to true or false...  Your code will run 100% exactly the same with the removal of the `== true`.  There's not a programming language in the world for which this is not true...

Comment: upgradesScroller.visible = !upgradesScroller.visible; ... your if/else/yes/no/true/false discussion is invalid ;)  I do not like mixing styles though, either stick to yes/no or true/false. Yes/no is the default for objc.

Comment: TRUE and YES are both valid synonyms for the same thing. (Same for FALSE and NO.) I use them interchangeably. Not sure about "true". I believe that's C language, not Objective C. The construct `if (value == TRUE)` or `if (value == YES)` is perfectly valid, and logically identical to `if (value)`. It's a question of style. Some find the `if (value == TRUE)` easier to read. nhgrif, no offense, but you are grasping at straws.

Comment: I do tend to agree with @LearnCocos2D that the if/else construct is needlessly complex and `upgradesScroller.visible = !upgradesScroller.visible` is much cleaner.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D Oh wow, that's a cool way to do it. I'll use that from now on. Any suggestions for my main issue? I don't think this guy is going to answer me anymore..

Comment: @LearnCocos2D Am I supposed to do this through a delegate?

Answer (score 1):

The question is a little confusing and the information is a bit incomplete, but I can only assume the problem is here:

```
UpgradesNew *upNew = [[UpgradesNew alloc]init];
```

I'm guessing `UpgradesNew` is some sort of view or view controller you've already instantiated and have on your screen.  When you call `[[UpgradesNew alloc] init];`, you're creating a new object.  What you need instead is a references to the currently existing `UpgradesNew` object that you intend to change.  You need to call the `changeColor` method on this existing object rather than creating a new one.

EDIT: If you want help on how to get a reference to the right object, you need a lot more detail in your question--as written, there's not much hint at the relationship between these objects.

Comment: Yes you are correct about that. How do I make a reference to the existing UpgradesNew? I can't just do '[UpgradesNew changeColor]' as I get an error.

Comment: Your question needs a lot more information.  I don't know the relationship between your objects.

Comment: I just added a bit more info

Comment: The information you added is completely irrelevant.  We're in agreement that the problem isn't the value of the bool, are we not?  Useful information would include any and all information describing the relationship between `MainScene` and any `UpgradesNew` objects that exist before we get to any of the posted code in question.

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure what exactly I need to provide. `MainScene` is a scene, and `UpgradesNew` is a layer. They are both just classes in my project with subclass of CCNode and contain code for their respective CCB files in SpriteBuilder. EDIT: The scrollview is a child of mainscene CCNode.

Comment: I don't know how I can possibly make it more clear that the ACTUAL CODE in which you instantiate `UpgradesNew` objects must be included AS CODE in your question.

Comment: I don't instantiate it in code. I'm using SpriteBuilder to do that. Every object that is on `UpgradesNew` is created on SB. I am just defining the objects there in the interface in header. `CCLabelTTF *label;`